# Cannot decode/encode in UTF-8

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, decoding

I have a text-box which allows users to enter a word.

```
The user enters: über
```

In the backend, I get the word like this:

```
def form_process(request):
    word = request.GET.get('the_word')
    word = word.encode('utf-8')
    #word = word.decode('utf-8')
    print word
```

For some reason, I cannot decode or encode this!!
It gives me the error:

```
 UnicodeEncodeError
 ('ascii', u'\ufffd', 0, 1, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

Edit: When I do "repr(word)", this is what I get:

```
u'\ufffd'
```

Comment: Did you really mean to create the `utf-9` tag? :D

Comment: What's `repr(word)` when you've just gotten it from the request?  That fffd is pretty strange...

Comment: Is this running from manage.py runserver or apache mod_python/wsgi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I had escape(word) ...in the javascript ...before I passed it to the server.

Comment: That would certainly mess things up. For constructing query strings from text you need `encodeURIComponent`. `escape` should never be used.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to put:

```
accept-charset="utf-8"
```

in the form tag?

EDIT: Is the DEFAULT_CHARSET in settings.py set to 'utf-8' ?

Comment: I added this, but it still has the same issue.

Comment: Don't use `accept-charset`. IE doesn't support it properly. You will continue to get strings encoded in the page's specified/guessed encoding; only characters that can't be encoded in that charset end up using UTF-8. And IE doesn't tell you which encoding it has used. If you want reliable UTF-8 form submissions you must specify the charset of the page containing the form to be UTF-8, using a Content-Type parameter or meta tag equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to use print word? If not, its should work without those lines.

```
def form_process(request):
    word = request.GET.get('the_word')
```